# All in one WP Migration Plugin Backup file is corrupted. Repair .wpress file

Tags: wordpress, plugins, migration

My hosting expired on 23 December and I took the backup of my site using the All in One WP migration plugin. Now I'm trying to import my backup and got this error " Unable to import, The Archive file is corrupted.
Please any senior guide me on how to resolve this issue. It's important because my previous hosting has expired and I've no other option except this backup.

[image]

First I tried to upload my backup directly using the plugin but didn't solve my problem. Then I upload my backup through the Hosting File Manager and restore my backup and it gives me an error.